# Redirect to an .aspx page from a MVC 4 Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, controller

I am pretty new to MVC and have been struggling with re directing between the various pages. 
I am trying to redirect to an aspx web forms page in the project root folder from am Controller.

Below are the solutions I tried:

1. public RedirectResult redirectToAspx()
       {
         return Redirect("~/Buffer.aspx");
       }
2. return Redirect("~/Buffer.aspx");
3. Taking out the

   handlers

   remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>

   add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />

   /handlers

   from System.WebServer

1 and 2 work when I run the project on my local machine but does not work when deploying onto Intranet IIS 7. 
Any ideas on why the redirect is being blocked would be greatly helpful?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? You should be more specific.

Comment: It redirects to the Error.cshtml in the default Shared Folder in my Views and gives the error "An error occurred while processing your request"

Comment: That means you got an error and you need to find out what the error is (check the machine logs in Windows Event Viewer, or configure the application to display the error, or log it to some sort of data store using tools such as [ELMAH](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/))

Answer (score 0):

You can add Error method in global file to find inner exception.

put debug point on exception line and got what is actual error on web server.

also you should check mime type for handler on web server IIS [Click here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/handlers/add).

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
            Response.Clear();

            HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;

            if (httpException != null)
            {
                string action;
                switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
                {
                    case 404:
                        // page not found
                        action = "HttpError404";
                        break;
                    case 500:
                        // server error
                        action = "HttpError500";
                        break;
                    default:
                        action = "Index";
                        break;
                }

                // clear error on server
                Server.ClearError();

                Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Error/{0}/?message={1}", action, exception.Message));
            }
        }
```

also you can do `<customErrors mode="Off" />` in web.config to find error on web page.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I added the above method in the Global.asax but still not seeing any particular error message. Am also developing on my local machine and then uploading the project to the web server, so no way of point break debugging and the redirects work fine on my localhost. 
I have also tried RedirectToAction and RedirectToRoute both of which wouldn't work on IIS.